# When tweaking memory settings (for stable overclocks) via BIOS, how do you know if a computer is hanging or in the middle of memory training?

Tags: overclocking

For my particular situation, the PC successfully past POST, loaded the Boot Loader, and handed over to OS, but the Splash Screen for Windows 10 is present but there is no loading circle animation, which to me looks like its hanging.

Not sure if its memory training or if its hanging.

I raised the voltage and RAM clock rate above JEDEC spec with a predefined profile, and didn't touch the memory timings.

Comment: What's "memory training"?  Do you mean testing? I see it is an actual term used by some OC's https://www.reddit.com/r/overclocking/comments/7z4cza/what_is_memory_training_does_it_really_work/ (apparently to refer to the firmware initializing the memory controller, and detecting the RAM etc.) but it seems patent nonsense to me to use such a term in this context.

Comment: @Fizz So, memory training is a process where the computer cycles through different combinations of "settings" for your memory (I.e., the main memory, i.e., your RAM) to have it function well before a successful OS boot in the case the settings are a little off as set by the BIOS. I am pretty sure it is not proprietary as you suggest. I think there are proprietary versions and similar proprietary processes as well. But, memory training exists among other processes that are run by DRAM (your memory) before being fully ready to work as memory for the CPU and other computer parts (components).

Comment: @Fizz I can undersatnd where you come from here. I guess its the same reason why I ask my question as there is a little mystery behind how memory training works and is implemented on accessible and free sources on the web. But, John gave a great reference actually. I understand why it could seem like a proprietary niche thing--it seems that there are not much reliable sources we can easily find on the internet, which is also why you may also suggest what you did about "memory training" appearing proprietary.

Comment: Here's a better link from @John's initial link:

https://www.systemverilog.io/design/ddr4-initialization-and-calibration/

Comment: @John: so it [seems](https://www.systemverilog.io/design/ddr4-initialization-and-calibration/) to refer to [ZQ calibration](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/Documents/Products/Technical%20Note/DRAM/TN4102.pdf) and the like. But the catch is that I've not seen any firmware that actually offers to do that periodically while the system is running [to compensate for thermal drift], as suggested there. As opposed to just at initialization.

Comment: @John: that sounds like something else entirely. The ZQ calibration (even for the long version) lasts 256-512 [memory] bus cycles, which is far, far shorter, although the bus needs to be idle, so still an issue on an active/running system.

Comment: Somewhat more usefully https://www.crucial.com/support/articles-faq-memory/ddr5-memory-training I've not looked at the DDR5 spec, but I'm surprised it can take so long.

Comment: TBH, it sounds like some bugs were involved as well https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht510469-memory-training-failure-with-coffeelake-cpu-and-micron-dimms-lenovo-thinksystem